# Swift - Incorrect Audio Sampler Midi Note

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, midi

So I have a multiple instrument samplers using AVFoundation and everything works great, I can play and stop notes, etc. Like this:

```
    sampler.startNote(note, withVelocity: 64, onChannel: 0)
```

And samplers are loaded with this function:

```
    func loadSoundBankInstrument(at bankURL: URL, 
                 program: UInt8, 
                 bankMSB: UInt8, 
                 bankLSB: UInt8) throws
```

One little issue I have is that whenever I play Midi notes above 120 they all sound the same. I tried with different samplers and they all have this issue. (I already checked the soundfonts and they work properly on DAW's like FLStudio). These notes are rarely used but still, would be good to know what's going on!

Not sure if it's a setting or maybe just a limitation of the sampler unit? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.